# What do I need to do to mount a USB drive in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux

What packages do I need to allow me to mount a USB drive in ArchLinux from the command line? What command do I use? Under Ubuntu these things happen automatically, but it's about time I learned how to do it like a pro

Answer (score 4):

```
mount /dev/sdXY /path/to/location/of/your/choice
```

Where XY is the sticks device node and partition (e.g. /dev/sdb1)

Answer (score 3):

Simply run `fdisk -l` to see what your USB device is called. Then make a directory - `mkdir /mnt/my_usb` - and mount it there: `mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/my_usb`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add this if anyone stumbles across this page again. 
I believe the packages "dosfstools" and "mtools" are required by Arch Linux to format FAT32 file systems. 
These tools don't come with the base Arch installation and are the reason why I had a similar problem with the USB drive not showing up and being unable to mount.